# Strange loop jump in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, sizeof

I'm trying to loop through a pointer array of objects and it works just fine until it reaches the input variable. Somehow it raises the size variable and keeps doing that until the application crashes. What is causing this strange behavior?

```
Array::Array(int in) 
{
    size = in;
    Heltal *h[sizeof(size)];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        h[i] = new Heltal(Array::Random(1, 100));
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Heltal *h[sizeof(size)];` be `Heltal *h[size];`?

Comment: That makes it complain about not being a constant value.

Comment: @Kraffs, Yes, because it needs to be a constant value. `sizeof(size)` does not magically make it a compile-time constant.

Comment: Then you will have to do something else, like use a vector.

Comment: @chris: `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, though it is wrong here of course.

Comment: @Kraffs: using sizeof(size) is wrong, because sizeof(size) will give you the size of the 'size' variable, which is fixed based on the type of the variable (most likely an int that's 32 bits, which would make sizeof() return 4) without regard for whether the value of size is 1 or 657368991.

Comment: @EdS., I meant it does not magically take a runtime value and turn it into a compile-time constant :)

Comment: @EdS. Heck, if it compiles then it must be right, no?

Comment: @chris: Ahh, I see what you were getting at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
Heltal *h[sizeof(size)];
```

With this:

```
std::vector<Heltal *> h(size);
```

`sizeof(size)` is a compile-time constant, and evaluates to the length, in bytes, of the type `size` is declared to be of.  This is likely to be a value of 4, which means that `h` will always be 4 elements long.  You are likely overflowing the array as a result.

The vector constructor will instead allocate a dynamic number of elements on the heap.

Comment: Ah! That explains a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @Kraffs: Actually, replace it with this so that you don't have to manually deallocate each element later; `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Heltal>>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you think `sizeof()` does, but what it's doing is returning the size of the variable `size`, which I'm guessing is `int` so it's probably returning `4`. The consequence of this is the size of your array is fixed based on the size of `int` rather than based on the value of `in`.

In C99 I'd say use `Heltal *h[size]`, but C++ doesn't allow for that. In this case I'd recommend just using a `std::vector<Heltal*>` instead and resizing it as appropriate.

Comment: I'd consider a smart pointer in addition to the vector.